# What happens when multiple users try to change the same data at the same time in a website's MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, runtime

Say a PHP script appends some text to an already existing data in a MySQL database. Say the existing data is `abc`. Now one user wants to append `123` and another wants to append `xyz`. Both of them run the script at the same time. Whose will be appended first? Will the final result be `abc123xyz` or `abcxyz123`?

At a worse case, say the script first takes the data, appends the given text to it, and then replaces the old data in the database. Then whose change will 'survive' here? Will the result be `abc123` or `abcxyz`?

Sorry if it has been asked before.

Comment: why not try it yourself and see what will happen?

Comment: @symbolicConstant How can I simulate multiple users doing something at the same time? It's mostly theoretical, but can happen in a website with a huge number of users. And even if I somehow simulate it, I will still need to know the explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the engine you use. For InnoDB MySQL performs row-level lock only for writes. 
There will be a tiny minute difference in hitting the database with the query

It will execute the first query.Then it will execute the second query
so the data will be either 123abc or 123xyz depending upon which query executed first.

Comment: So, theoretically if 2 scripts run the same update query (but with different modifications) at exactly the same server time (up to the nanosecond or even more accurate), even then there will be a queue and one query will run first and then the next, right?

Comment: Right as per my knowledge.